# 2 partition problem with equal cardinality

Tags: ds.algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Faster pseudo-polynomial time algorithms for PARTITION](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4644/faster-pseudo-polynomial-time-algorithms-for-partition)

I want to partition N given numbers( may or may not be equal) into 2 subsets such that the 2 subsets have sum as close as possible and also the cardinality of the sets are equal ( if n is even ) or differ only by 1 ( if n is odd)

I think we can do this in pseudo polynomial time O(n^2 * Sum of set)

Can I do better than this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @awoodland Why's that? CST faq suggests otherwise.

Comment: Does `O(2^(n/2))` count as better?

Comment: @awoodland, This isn't a CSTheory level problem and @Firebrandt I think this is exactly 2-Partition problem, see wiki for details, or clarify your question with more details.

Comment: What is the best algorithm(pseudo polynomial) to solve this problem?

Comment: See wiki carefully, partition is a problem on "multiset" not set.

Comment: @Firebrandt You can make it a 2 partition problem if you replace equal values with slightly different ones. (By this, I mean that the sum of all the differences applied must be less than 0.5.) But as it has been pointed out, you can just treat them as multisets.

Comment: oh.. i dint see multiset..

Comment: I am looking for the optimisation version the partition problem ( as given in wiki) . the cardinality of the subsets must be equal(if even) or differ by one(if odd) and in addition the sum of the subsets must be as close as possible , i.e Minimise (Sum (subset1) - sum(subset2))

Comment: @ Saeed , I am deleting the previous wrong comment of mine..I am sorry about that i got confused...

Comment: @IVlad no 2^n/2 is not better...

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4462531/545637

Comment: Ask on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The asker had (secretly) posted the same question both on cstheory.stackexchange.com and Stack Overflow, and the question on Stack Overflow was migrated here.  Seems like another reason why simultaneous crossposting and crossposting without linking are bad.  Voted to close as an exact duplicate.

Comment: I have started a [meta discussion](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/919/186) about migration.